# CDI managed beans inheritance till sub most object level.

Tags: cdi

I have below case.

### A.java:-

@Named("a1")

@ApplicationScoped
class A{

}

### B.java:-

@Specializes

class B extends A{

}

### C.java:-

@Specializes

class C extends B{

}

When I'm using EL language in .xhtml page as (a1.orderForm) it is always pointing B class object.

Can somebody tell me what I have done wrong here in order to point the C class object.

Comment: What you show here is correct - you can easily verify that with Weld SE for instance. You will need to add more detailed info, the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: It should work. Are you sure that C class is in the classpath? How is packaged your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my bad that Class C is not in the classpath due to maven exclusions while packaging it.